# How to find specific text with extension in Batch File and then move it

Tags: batch-file, cmd

First off, I'm new to batch files.

I want to find all files with extension `.txt` in a folder and then scan them so that it scans the 5th line of the text file which is in the format:

```
txt||||open.doc|||
```

It then fetches this doc file and gives it as output

This is the code I am using:

```
@echo off

for %%f in (*.txt) do (
 if "%%~xf"==".txt" do (
   for /f "tokens=1* delims=:img|||" %%a in ('findstr /n .* %%f') do (
    if "%%a" equ "4" (
      echo.%%b
      set str=%%b
      set str=%str:~1,-1%
      echo str: %str%
    )
   )
  )
 )

pause
```

Comment: So - where are you stuck? Show us the code, man.

Comment: I am unable to fetch the doc file name and show it as the output

Comment: My output should be open.doc or but it is giving the following output: open.doc|||

Comment: Try `for /F "tokens=2 delims=|" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" *.txt ^| findstr ":5:"') do echo %%a`. This performs what your _description_ says (I don't understand your code).

Answer (score 0):

```
 if "%%~xf"==".txt" do (
```

change to

```
 if /I "%%~xf"==".txt" do (
```

to allow `txt` in any case.

`delims=:img|||` means delimiters are `:`,`i`,`m`,`g` and `|`. The delimiters are a **set**, not a **string**.

Tips : Use `set "var1=data"` for setting string values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces. In comparisons; don't assign a terminal `\`, space or quotes - build pathnames from the elements - counterintuitively, it is likely to make the process easier.
Use `if "thing1" == "thing2" ...` to avoid problems caused by spaces in `thing1/2`.

You need `delayedexpansion` because `str` is being varied within the loop. See
[Stephan's DELAYEDEXPANSION link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2128947)

Comment: I'll assume that `if "%%a" equ "4" ` is correct - it's your file(s)